# Multiple post requests within same session is not working while web scraping ASP.NET site

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape Time Table data from my university webpage(link provided in the code). On-webpage I have to select a course in the drop-down list and the year studying in(1-4). After selecting, I would be able to see the time table. I have tried implementing the same using python and its libraries. requests, urllib, beautifulsoup has helped me before with scraping the data with normal pages but I am not able to do so in this scenario. Please help me with this.

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import *
import requests
import json

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    url = "http://www.timetable.ul.ie/UA/CourseTimetable.aspx"

    with requests.Session() as session:
        r = session.get(url)
        cookies = r.cookies
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        viewstate = soup.select("#__VIEWSTATE")[0]['value']
        viewstategen = soup.select("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")[0]['value']
        eventvalidation = soup.select("#__EVENTVALIDATION")[0]['value']

        headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0','Referer': 'https://www.timetable.ul.ie/UA/CourseTimetable.aspx'}
        data = {
            '__EVENTTARGET': 'ctl00$HeaderContent$CourseDropdown',
            '__VIEWSTATE': viewstate,
            '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': viewstategen,
            '__EVENTVALIDATION': eventvalidation,
            'ctl00$HeaderContent$CourseDropdown':'LM338-Master+of+Science+in+Software+Engineering'
        }
        
        r1 = requests.post(url=url, data=json.dumps(data), cookies=cookies, headers = headers)
        soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r1.text, 'html.parser')
        viewstate= soup1.select("#__VIEWSTATE")[0]['value']
        viewstategen = soup1.select("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")[0]['value']
        eventvalidation = soup1.select("#__EVENTVALIDATION")[0]['value']
        
        data = {
            '__EVENTTARGET': 'ctl00$HeaderContent$CourseYearDropdown',
            '__VIEWSTATE': viewstate,
            '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': viewstategen,
            '__EVENTVALIDATION': eventvalidation,
            'ctl00$HeaderContent$CourseYearDropdown': '1'
        }

        r2 = requests.post(url=url, data=json.dumps(data), cookies=cookies, headers = headers)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, 'html.parser')
        print(soup2)```


The Output that I am getting now has all the list of courses in the university, which are there in the dropdown list.
````

Answer (score 1):

This example will get timetable for first course and first year. You can adapt this example and get timetables for all courses/all years (loop over the `courses` list):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url1 = "https://www.timetable.ul.ie/UA/Default.aspx"
url2 = "https://www.timetable.ul.ie/UA/CourseTimetable.aspx"

with requests.session() as s:
    s.get(url1)  # load cookies
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url2).content, "html.parser")

    data = {
        "__EVENTTARGET": "ctl00$HeaderContent$CourseDropdown",
        "__EVENTARGUMENT": "",
        "__LASTFOCUS": "",
        "ctl00$HeaderContent$CourseDropdown": "",  # <-- this will be filled from `courses` list below
    }

    for inp in soup.select("input[value]"):
        data[inp["name"]] = inp["value"]

    courses = [
        opt["value"]
        for opt in soup.select("#HeaderContent_CourseDropdown option")
        if opt["value"] != "-1"
    ]

    # get timetable for first course:
    data["ctl00$HeaderContent$CourseDropdown"] = courses[0]

    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.post(url2, data=data).content, "html.parser")

    # uncomment this to print all courses:
    # print(*courses, sep="\n")

    years = [
        opt["value"]
        for opt in soup.select("#HeaderContent_CourseYearDropdown option")
        if opt["value"] != "-1"
    ]

    # get timetable for first year:
    data["ctl00$HeaderContent$CourseYearDropdown"] = years[0]
    for inp in soup.select("input[value]"):
        data[inp["name"]] = inp["value"]

    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.post(url2, data=data).content, "html.parser")

    # print some data:
    print(
        soup.select_one("table#MainContent_CourseTimetableGridView").get_text(
            strip=True, separator="\n"
        )
    )
```

Prints:

```
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
09:00 - 10:00
AC4002 - TUT - 3J
EGAN VANESSA MS
Wks:1-9,11-13
Online Yr 1
09:00 - 10:00
EC4102 - TUT - 3J
TA1ECO

...
```